# R JSON to UTF-8 not encoded correctly

Tags: json, r, utf-8, get, character-encoding

I'm pulling JSON data from an API. The API translates a destination name into different languages, therefore i need it to be in UTF-8 to understand all the special characters etc.

I'm using the following code to pull the JSON from the API and then use UTF-8 encoding:

```
 localisedDestinationNameForGivenLang <- function (LocationId) {
   gaiaURL <- paste0("http://API",LocationId, "?geoVersion=rwg&lcid=", "1036", 
"&cid=geo&apk=explorer")
  text <- content(GET(gaiaURL), as = "text", encoding = "UTF-8")
 return(tryCatch(fromJSON(text), error=function(e) NULL))
}
```

However, it's still returning this:
New York (et environs), New York, Ã‰tats-Unis d'AmÃ©rique

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the data you’re getting *actually* encoded in UTF-8?

Comment: @Biffen - how can i check this?

Comment: An HTTP response should have a content type header with a charset. If there isn't one it defaults to ISO 8859-1 (IIRC).

Comment: @Biffen - I narrowed down the issue. I use the laply function to run this function across thousands of DestinationId's, then ldply to transform the output class from list of list to dataframe. ldply seems to be removing the encoding. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: No, sorry. I can only recommend reading up on encodings in general.